# How to “allow” permission by default in “auto start manager” from android code

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Not getting GCM Notification if app is closed or swiped off from task manager when auto start permission is deny in 'auto start manager' application.

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: You can't. Denying or granting access permissions to apps is a user's privilege.